# What is the best way to create blocks of items in D3.JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

Well I am new to D3.JS, and I am quite surprise about the way to create svg blocks the I found overwhelming, I'll explain my self I need for example to code an HTML div block like this [image]

with HTML and CSS it quite easy and simple and the code is reusable, with D3 I found my self defining item by attem attaching them to the root svg by an Append and static x and y and some weird ways to add glyphs, well it gives me something like that:

```
svg.attr({ width: 500, height: 500 });

    var rectangle = svg.append("rect").
    attr("width", 300).
    attr("height", 100).attr("fill", "#3b3e3f");


    var rectangleIndexes = svg.append("rect").
    attr("width", 50).
    attr("height", 100).attr("fill", "#303233");

    var edit = svg.append("rect").
    attr("width", 30).
    attr("height", 30).
    attr("x", 10).
    attr("y", 10).
    attr("fill", "#454a4d");

    var editBtn = svg.append("svg:foreignObject")
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("height", 20)
        .attr("y", "15px")
        .attr("x", "18px")
        .append("xhtml:span")
        .attr("class", "control glyphicon glyphicon-pencil")
        .attr("style", "color :#fff");

etc...
```

Is there any other way(s) to do this since I am used to html/css it will be great if we can import an html code inside an svg or something more simple and reusable.

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First question, if you want HTML/CSS why are you appending them to SVG?

Second thing, `d3` doesn't mean you can't use CSS.  You don't have to in-line styles if you don't want.  Just assign them a class.

Third, you are missing the point of `d3`.  It's all about driving your display through data (the 3 ds are **d**ata **d**riven **d**ocuments).  Your data here would be an array element for each "block".

Something like this (please forgive my horrible CSS):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.17" data-semver="3.5.17" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
    <style>
      .my-block {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: steelblue;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
        float: left;
        margin: 20px;
        position: relative;
      }
      .icon {
          position:absolute;
          top: 80px;
          right: 5px;
          color: #fff;
      }
      .text {
          position:absolute;
          top: 40px;
          left: 25px;
          color: #fff;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
    var data = [
      {
        name: "block 1",
        icon: "glyphicon-pencil"
      },{
        name: "block 2",
        icon: "glyphicon-film"
      },{
        name: "block 3",
        icon: "glyphicon-off"
      },{
        name: "block 4",
        icon: "glyphicon-user"
      }
    ];
    
    var body = d3.select('body');
    
    var divs = body.selectAll('.my-block')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('div')
      .attr('class', 'my-block')
      
    divs.append('span')
      .text(function(d){
        return d.name;
      })
      .attr("class", "text");
      
    divs.append('span')
      .attr("class", function(d){
        return "icon control glyphicon " + d.icon;
      });
    
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I choose SVG cause I want to draw tree views with my blocks and some zooming/panning and drag/drop